# Delete characters from OpenSSH client

Tags: linux, bash, go, ssh, terminal

I'm writing an SSH server in Golang. Currently I have a server which can read and write from/to the client. When the client presses the delete key the server receives unicode character 13 (delete). I can rewrite the current line by sending all but the deleted character to the client. However, it only rewrites as many characters as I send. This means the last characters don't get re-written until new characters are entered. Does anyone know what the server needs to send in order for characters to be deleted from the client.

### Client

Operating system: Ubuntu 16.04

Ssh version: 1.2.12

Bash version: 4.3

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Unicode code point 13 is Carriage Return; Delete is 127 and Backspace is 8. And from the description I'm pretty sure that you are mixing up terminal emulation and SSH; an SSH server (or an SSH client, for that matter) does not and should not do terminal emulation -- that's the job of a terminal emulator.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: @shellter Yes it is about programming!  This is a question about the behaviour of ssh clients from the programmer's perspective, for the purpose of writing a program.  Please READ THE QUESTION before voting to close!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is send a space `" "`.

But I suspect you are going about this in the wrong way.  SSH is just a way to let a user access a terminal.  It is not a command line processor.  That's the job of Bash or whatever other command line the user has selected.  Bash should be able to handle this type of logic as it's designed to talk to a terminal.  Re-implementing bash in go-lang is a huge task and if that's what you want to do then good luck!

To avoid these problems (and make lot less work for yourself) you should be using a [Pseudo Terminal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html) to talk to bash not a pipe.  If you do so then I believe bash should correctly handle backspaces for you.

You may also want to look at "[Using Pseudo Terminals to Control Interactive Programs](http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html)"